# Orgmode - Vertical header

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

is it possible to create a vertical header with org mode, too?

Something like this (cyan colored fields):

[image]

You can create a horizontal header like this:

```
| Header  | Header  | Header  | Header  | Header  |
|---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| Content | Content | Content | Content | Content |
```

but I want also a vertical header, too:

```
| Header | Header  | Header  | Header  | Header  |
|--------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| Header | Content | Content | Content | Content |
| Header | Content | Content | Content | Content |
```

The reason for this is I want to export it to HTML.

The HTML will look like this:

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" frame="hsides" rules="groups">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">.</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">1</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">2</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">3</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">4</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">5</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">6</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">7</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">8</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">9</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">10</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">11</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">12</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="org-right">1</td>
                <td class="org-right">1</td>
                <td class="org-right">2</td>
                <td class="org-right">3</td>
                <td class="org-right">4</td>
                <td class="org-right">5</td>
                <td class="org-right">6</td>
                <td class="org-right">7</td>
                <td class="org-right">8</td>
                <td class="org-right">9</td>
                <td class="org-right">10</td>
                <td class="org-right">11</td>
                <td class="org-right">12</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

if it supports vertical header it should be something like this:

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" frame="hsides" rules="groups">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
            <col class="org-right">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">.</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">1</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">2</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">3</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">4</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">5</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">6</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">7</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">8</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">9</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">10</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">11</th>
                <th class="org-right" scope="col">12</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="org-right">1</th>
                <td class="org-right">1</td>
                <td class="org-right">2</td>
                <td class="org-right">3</td>
                <td class="org-right">4</td>
                <td class="org-right">5</td>
                <td class="org-right">6</td>
                <td class="org-right">7</td>
                <td class="org-right">8</td>
                <td class="org-right">9</td>
                <td class="org-right">10</td>
                <td class="org-right">11</td>
                <td class="org-right">12</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Note the `th` element on the second code block instead of an `td` element on the `tbody`. I know I can do this with JavaScript but I want to know if `org-mode` may already support it, which would make things a lot easier.

Comment: Updated question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the first column a "header" column, all you have to do is

```el
(setq org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column t)
```

either globally, or as a [local file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables):

```
# Local Variables:
# org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column: t
# End:
```

AFAIK, you cannot specify it per table though.

For example:

```org
* Multiplication table

  #+ATTR_HTML: :border 3 :rules all :frame border
  |  . |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |   9 |  10 |
  |----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----|
  |  1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |   9 |  10 |
  |  2 |  2 |  4 |  6 |  8 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 |  18 |  20 |
  |  3 |  3 |  6 |  9 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 |  27 |  30 |
  |  4 |  4 |  8 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 | 28 | 32 |  36 |  40 |
  |  5 |  5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 |  45 |  50 |
  |  6 |  6 | 12 | 18 | 24 | 30 | 36 | 42 | 48 |  54 |  60 |
  |  7 |  7 | 14 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 42 | 49 | 56 |  63 |  70 |
  |  8 |  8 | 16 | 24 | 32 | 40 | 48 | 56 | 64 |  72 |  80 |
  |  9 |  9 | 18 | 27 | 36 | 45 | 54 | 63 | 72 |  81 |  90 |
  | 10 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 |  90 | 100 |
  #+TBLFM: @2$2..@>$> = @1$0 * @0$1


* Local variables                                      :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column: t
# End:
```

will be exported to HTML exactly as you show (except for the colors).

See the [Tables in HTML export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html#Tables-in-HTML-export) section of the manual for other variables, but beware of the `#+ATTR_HTML` syntax: it's as I show above for recent versions of Org mode, but the manual shows the old syntax:

```org
 #+ATTR_HTML: border="2" rules="all" frame="border"
```

which you might still have to employ, depending on your version. I'll open a bug about the doc.

---

[OLD ANSWER: the following does not answer the question but it might be sufficiently interesting  to leave in here.]

If you mean something like this:

```
* Multiplication table


  |  . |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |   9 |  10 |  11 |  12 |
  |  1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |   9 |  10 |  11 |  12 |
  |  2 |  2 |  4 |  6 |  8 | 10 | 12 | 14 | 16 |  18 |  20 |  22 |  24 |
  |  3 |  3 |  6 |  9 | 12 | 15 | 18 | 21 | 24 |  27 |  30 |  33 |  36 |
  |  4 |  4 |  8 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 | 28 | 32 |  36 |  40 |  44 |  48 |
  |  5 |  5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 35 | 40 |  45 |  50 |  55 |  60 |
  |  6 |  6 | 12 | 18 | 24 | 30 | 36 | 42 | 48 |  54 |  60 |  66 |  72 |
  |  7 |  7 | 14 | 21 | 28 | 35 | 42 | 49 | 56 |  63 |  70 |  77 |  84 |
  |  8 |  8 | 16 | 24 | 32 | 40 | 48 | 56 | 64 |  72 |  80 |  88 |  96 |
  |  9 |  9 | 18 | 27 | 36 | 45 | 54 | 63 | 72 |  81 |  90 |  99 | 108 |
  | 10 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 |  90 | 100 | 110 | 120 |
  | 11 | 11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55 | 66 | 77 | 88 |  99 | 110 | 121 | 132 |
  | 12 | 12 | 24 | 36 | 48 | 60 | 72 | 84 | 96 | 108 | 120 | 132 | 144 |
  #+TBLFM: @2$2..@>$> = @1$0 * @0$1
```

the answer is an emphatic YES.

I created the table with the following set of instructions:

- `M-x org-create-table RET 1x13 RET`: that creates a single column table with 13 rows.
- Type `.` in the first row, `1` in the second row and then keep typing `S-<Enter>` to fill the rest of the rows.
- `M-x org-table-transpose-table-at-point RET` to make it into a single row table.
- Press `TAB` to create the second row and move to the first column of it.
- Type `1` in the first column of the second row and then keep typing `S-<Enter>` to fill out the rest of that column.

You now have the first column and the first row, populated with what you show in your table. Now add a table formula under the table as shown above and press `C-c C-c`: the rest of the table gets filled out (you must activate Calc beforehand: type `M-x calc RET q` to do that).

The table formula says: fill out every other cell in the table (rows 2 to last and columns 2 to last) with the product of the numbers that you find in (row 1, current column) and (current row, column 1).

Comment: I didn't meant the calculation (but didn't knew that either, so thanks). I don't know how I can do a vertical header. I updated my question for better understanding.